# Implement merge_sort with multiprocessing solution

Tags: python

I tried to write a merge sort with multiprocessing solution

```
from heapq import merge
from multiprocessing import Process

def merge_sort1(m):
    if len(m) < 2:
        return m

    middle = len(m) // 2
    left = Process(target=merge_sort1, args=(m[:middle],))
    left.start()
    right = Process(target=merge_sort1, args=(m[middle:],))
    right.start()
    for p in (left, right):
        p.join()
    result = list(merge(left, right))
    return result
```

Test it with arr

```
In [47]: arr = list(range(9))                                                                                   
In [48]: random.shuffle(arr)
```

It repost error:

```
In [49]: merge_sort1(arr)                                                                                       
TypeError: 'Process' object is not iterable
```

What's the problem with my code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`merge(left, right)` tries to merge two processes, whereas you presumably want to merge the two lists that resulted from each process. Note that return value of the function passed to `Process` is lost; it is a different process, not just a different thread, and you can't very easily shuffle data back to parent, so Python doesn't do that, by default. You need to be explicit and code such a channel yourself. Fortunately, there are `multiprocessing` datatypes to help you; for example, `multiprocessing.Pipe`:

```
from heapq import merge
import random
import multiprocessing

def merge_sort1(m, send_end=None):
    if len(m) < 2:
        result = m
    else:
        middle = len(m) // 2

        inputs = [m[:middle], m[middle:]]
        pipes = [multiprocessing.Pipe(False) for _ in inputs]
        processes = [multiprocessing.Process(target=merge_sort1, args=(input, send_end))
                    for input, (recv_end, send_end) in zip(inputs, pipes)]
        for process in processes: process.start()
        for process in processes: process.join()
        results = [recv_end.recv() for recv_end, send_end in pipes]

        result = list(merge(*results))

    if send_end:
        send_end.send(result)
    else:
        return result


arr = list(range(9))
random.shuffle(arr)

print(merge_sort1(arr))
```